# Linux Command to list all users by uid

Tags: linux, terminal, redhat

I am using RedHat Linux 6.
I need redhat Linux terminal code to list all the users above uid=499?
i already tried "cat /etc/passwd". but it shows all users. how do i filter it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [awk](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/) to parse the passwd database for the UIDs you want.

To list all the users for UIDs strictly greater than 499, do this:

```
awk -F ':' '$3 > 499' /etc/passwd
```

EDIT: If you only want the usernames, do this:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 499 {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in your terminal to find all user

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

hope this code help you thanx